# Firebase sends topic notifications to every users on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-notifications

Hi I'm using firebase to manage the notifications, but when I handle a message with my index.js, sendToTopic function send notification without check the topic.

So I've tried to send a message with firebase's console, and it's the same.
During the users registration, on iOS environment, I don't subscribe user to anything, but still receives the notification.

My index.js is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('topics/{code}/')
.onWrite(event =>{

var request              = event.data.val();
var signals              = request.signals;
var index                = Object.keys(signals).length-1;
var lastSignalKey        = Object.keys(signals)[index];
var lastSignal           = signals[lastSignalKey];
var code                 = lastSignal.code;
var uid                  = lastSignal.uid;
var type                 = lastSignal.type;
var when                 = lastSignal.when;
var sound                = "sound.aiff";


var payload = {
    notification : {
        body : "mMessage",
        title : "MoVeng",
        "sound" : sound
    },
    data: {
        uid:  uid,
        code: code,
        type: type,
        when: when
    }
};


let signal = admin.database()
                    .ref("topics/"+ 
                         code + "/"+
                         type+ "/"+
                         uid);
signal.remove(); 

admin.messaging().sendToTopic(code, payload).then(function(response){
    console.log("Success: ",response);
})
    .catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error: ",error);
})
});
```

I've tried to googling, but no one has this problem.

I don't understand why notifications come in if no ID, no handler, no token are passed through the notification, just the topic name, and sendToTopic doesn't do what it should do.

this is my appDelegate code, if it can help someone to help me:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging

 @UIApplicationMain
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder,    UIApplicationDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
  public static var active = false
  var window: UIWindow?
  let sharedInstance = FirebaseAPI()
  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
  var data : NSDictionary?

override init(){
    super.init()

    let logs = defaults.object(forKey: "logs")
    print(String(describing: logs))
    UIFont.overrideInitialize()
}
func getData() -> NSDictionary?{
    return data
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {



    if let options = launchOptions
    {
        let params = options[.remoteNotification] as! NSDictionary
        data = params


    }
    else
    {
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (authenticated, error) in
    }
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

    }
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    sharedInstance.findCode(forUser: (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!) { (code) in
        if let notificationCode = notification.request.content.userInfo["code"] as! String?
        {
            if (notificationCode.isEqual(code))
            {
                completionHandler([.badge, .alert, .sound])
            }
        }
    }

}





func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let request = response.notification.request
    print("mah")
    if response.actionIdentifier == "moveng"
    {
        let whoSignaledMe = request.content.userInfo["whoSignaledMe"] as? String
        let signal = Signal.getAnswer(code: whoSignaledMe!)
        FirebaseAPI.getNotificationKey(forUser: whoSignaledMe!,
                                        ofType:  "answers").setValue(signal.get());
       }
       completionHandler()
   } 


     func application(_ application: UIApplication,   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping   (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
   }


}
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: If you're absolutely positive that the a client is receiving messages from a topic it is not subscribe to, the this is already an unexoected behavior. I suggest reaching out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to have them take a look at this. Don't forget to provide as much details as you can.

Comment: If you want to troubleshoot this, you can get status of an app instance, including any topic subscriptions.  You need to compose an HTTP request as [described here](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances).  Not too hard to do using a browser app like ARC or Postman.

Comment: @AL. yeah I do. When I try to send notification to a specific topic from firebase, which client is not subscribed to, I get the notification the same.
I think it's a register problem, does Firebase subscribe the application instance or just the logged user?

Comment: @ArchimediaElettronica: Subscription is for the application instance

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @BobSnyder so I can wait till Auth.auth().signout() success before unsuscribe user from his topics?